# $u$ substitution leads to invalid result

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute:

$$
\oint_C \frac{2}{z(z+2)} \, dz
$$

where $C$ is the circle (in the complex plane) $|z| = 1$. I tried the following:

Parameterize with $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$, so $\gamma'(t) = i e^{it}$. Plug in and simplify to arrive at:

$$
\int_{t=0} \frac{2i}{e^{it} + 2} \, dt
$$

Let $u = -it$ and substitute:

$$
\int_{u=0}^{-2\pi i} \frac{-2}{e^{-u} + 2} \, du 
= \int_{u=0}^{-2\pi i} \frac{-2 e^u}{1 + 2e^u} \, du
$$

Next, we want to let $v = 1 + 2 e^u$. But then $v(0) = 1 +  2e^0 = 3$ and $v(-2\pi i) = 1 + 2^{-2\pi i} = 3$, so the integral is $0$, which doesn't match what I find from e.g. WolframAlpha.

What went wrong here? I think there is something unsound about $u$-substituting with a multivalued function but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: One of the poles ($z = -1$) lies on the contour $C$. Therefore the integral can not converge. If you change the contour a little bit such that no poles lie on $C$, you can use the residue theorem to calculate the integral.

Comment: Your substitution requires that $u(v)$ is differentiable at all points in the contour. However, the contour in $v$ wraps around a logarithmic singularity, which means it always passes through a non-differentiable branch cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version avoiding the pole on the contour.

$$
\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{2}{z(z+2)} \, dz = 2 i \pi
$$
by residue theorem.  Substitute $z=e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$
to get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2i}{e^{it}+2}\;dt = 2\pi i
$$
Substitute $u=-it$ to get
$$
\int_0^{-2 i \pi}\frac{-2}{e^{-u}+2}\;du = 2\pi i
$$
The path of integration is a line segment from $0$ to $-2i\pi$.
Next substitue $v = 1+2e^u$.  So $v$ goes around a circle, centered at $1$, radius $2$, starting at $3$ and ending at $3$.  It is not correct to write this as
$$
\int_3^3 \frac{1}{v}\;dv = 0 .
$$
Instead it should be written as
$$
\int_{|v-1|=2} \frac{1}{v}\; dv = 2\pi i
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your aproach is wrong because it implicitly uses the fact that $\frac{2e^u}{1+2e^u}$ has a primitive. Which primitive? If you are thinking about $\log(1+2e^u)$, then you have a huge problem there, since $\log$ is not a function; each complex number other than $0$ has infinitely many logarithms.

Comment: There was a typo in the initial statement -- it should have been $z(z+2)$ in the denominator rather than $z(z+1)$. I don't fully follow the second half -- it is ok for $\log$ to show up as an antiderivative, right? e.g. $\oint_C \frac{1}{z}$ around the origin is well-defined.

Comment: Yes, $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\mathrm dz}z$ is well defined. Actually, it is equal to $2\pi i$. What has that to do with $\log$ showing up in an antiderivative?